# Instagram gem returns full hash after iterating through it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram

I am using the instagram gem with rails. My problem is I am iterating over all of the data in the response with code like this:

```
<div>
<ul>
  <%= @instagram.each do |pic| %>
    <li><%= pic.name %></li>
    <li><%= pic.latitude%></li>
    <li><%= pic.longitude%></li>
  <% end %> 
</ul>
</div>
```

I am getting the desired results except for the end, where this gets printed in the browser:

```
[#<Hashie::Mash id="152201866" latitude=45.89172 longitude=-64.370013 name="Marshview Middle School">, ... etc...]
```

Any help trying to figure out how to ignore that last bit would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is the return value for `each`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
<%= @instagram.each do |pic| %>
```

to

```
<% @instagram.each do |pic| %>
```

`=` expects a return and prints the collection it iterates over.